# listview to string exception thrown

Tags: c#, winforms

What I have going on is i am using

```
string proj = listView2.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
```

to capture the item of my selected listview item, this works fine the first around, when i click on another listview item it throw the exception of

> InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
>   Parameter name: index

Any thoughts?

```
    private void listView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string proj = listView2.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
    }
```

working:

```
        string proj ="";
        ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection lv2si =
        this.listView2.SelectedItems;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in lv2si)
        {
            proj = item.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if no item is selected in listview ? The collection will contain zero items and it will throw this exception.

Instead, obtain ListViewItemCollection and use foreach to iterate over it. As described in MSDN example:
ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection breakfast = 
            this.ListView1.SelectedItems;

```
    double price = 0.0;
    foreach ( ListViewItem item in breakfast )
    {
        price += Double.Parse(item.SubItems[1].Text);
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should test that the index value is valid before you access it.

```
private void listView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    string proj;
    if (listView2.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        proj = listView2.SelectedItems[0].ToString(); 
    else
        proj = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event is raised whenever the `Selected` property of a `ListViewItem` changes.  This means the event is raised *twice*:  once when the first item is deselected, and a second time when the item you clicked on is selected.  Since you are not checking whether `SelectedItems` has any items, you get the exception the first time the event is raised.

As @Jeffrey L Whitledge shows in his answer, you can use `SelectedItems.Count` to determine whether any items are selected.